# Laravel macro collection - Call to a member function map() on null

Tags: laravel, macros, filtering, laravel-livewire, meilisearch

I have a project that i want to add a filter functionality to it using meilisearch.
And what I'm trying to do is creating a new macro collection,

```php
// App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

    public function boot(): void
    {
        Collection::macro('recursive', function () {
            $this->map(function ($value) {
                if (is_null($value)) return;
                if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                    return collect($value)->recursive();
                }

                return $value;

            });
        });
    }
```

And when I'm trying to call the macro to filter,

```php
// dd($this->queryFilters)
/*
array:2 [▼ // app\Http\Livewire\ProductBrowser.php:26
  "color" => []
  "size" => []
]
*/

$filters = collect($this->queryFilters)
    ->filter(fn ($filter) => !empty($filter))
    ->recursive()
    ->map(function ($value, $key) {
        return $value->map(fn ($value) => $key . ' = "' . $value . '"');
    })
    ->flatten()
    ->join('AND');
    
    dd($filters);
```

It gives me `Error:Call to a member function map() on null` it seems to be the "recursive()" function that returns null.

I tried to add the recursive macro to the collection.

I think the problem is in the "recursive()" and maybe in meilisearch version I don't really know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you update your `marcro` like following "just to ensure you imported the `Collection`

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Collection::macro('recursive', function () {
    return $this->map(function ($value) {
        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
            return collect($value)->recursive();
        }

        return $value;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems that it was the problem.

Comment: You are welcome, it is only the missing `return`